# Read handwritten values using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using Apache PDFBox to read a scanned PDF document.

In my PDF document there are handwritten text for some of the fields. I am not able to read them using PDFBox.

Is there a way to read the handwritten values for fields in the form?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a representative screenshot of the PDF you are working with, as well as a minimal Java method you are using to parse the document. Has this PDF already had OCR run on it (e.g., via Adobe Acrobat or some other third-party application)? I can't tell if this is an OCR question or a PDFBox API question. More details will attract better answers.

Comment: Please share the PDF and mention what version you are using.

Comment: Indeed, without an example file we can hardly help you.